# What's the Difference Between 'err' and 'errmsg' in a PHP MongoDB Driver Result Array?

Tags: php, mongodb

The [manual for the PHP MongoDB Driver](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php) describes two different result array elements that seem to do the same thing: `err` and `errmsg` for insert/remove operations (at least, when write concerns are used).

> **err**
>
> If this field is non-null, an error occurred on the previous operation. If this field is set, it will be a string describing the error that occurred.
>
> **errmsg**
>
> This field is set if something goes wrong with a database command. It is coupled with ok being 0. For example, if w is set and times out, errmsg will be set to "timed out waiting for slaves" and ok will be 0. If this field is set, it will be a string describing the error that occurred.

Do these contain the same error message string? Is there additional information to be gained from one vs. the other? If I was going to use only one, which would contain the most descriptive error message, and which is most proper to use?

I'm confused as to why both exist. I realize that `errmsg` was added in 2.6, and I'm using 2.6, but this seems to be redundant... Thanks!

Comment: I have the same doubt. Have you got the answer ?